# Finding the URL for an AKS Cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've set-up an AKS cluster and am now trying to connect to it.  My deployment YAML is here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec: 
  containers:
    - name: dockertest20190205080020
      image: dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io/dockertest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 443
metadata: 
  name: my-test
```

If I run the dashboard, I get this:

[image: KubernetesDashboard]

Which looks like it should be telling me the external endpoint, but isn't.  I have a theory that this is because the Yaml file is only deploying a Pod, which is in some way not able to expose an endpoint - is that the case and if so, why?  Otherwise, how can I find this endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not how that works, you need to read up on basic kubernetes concept. Pods are only container, to expose pods you need to create services (and you need labels), to expose pods externally you need to set service type to LoadBalancer. You probably want to use deployments instead of pods, its a lot easier\reliable.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

so in short, you need to add labels to your pod and create a service of type load balancer with selectors that match your pods labels

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 443
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: As you say, I am new to Kubernetes - apologies for that.  However, I have two questions based on your answer: the sample that you've posted above: does that sit in the same yaml file as the one that deploys the pods, or are they different files (or can it be either)?  Also, in the documentation that you've linked (which I have already come across) it states that a Pod has it's own IP - my impression was that it was possible to connect to that.

Comment: 1. can be both. 2. that is an internal address, you can certainly connect to that from inside the cluster network

Comment: Thanks - so where would I find an example of a Yaml file that had both Pod and Service in it?  I was under the impression that "Kind" could only be one thing

Comment: literally anywhere in the web? :) https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/