# Not able to connect to an AKS Service Endpoint

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Following on from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685755/finding-the-url-for-an-aks-cluster/54685867?noredirect=1#comment96165733_54685867), I now have the issue that I am unable to connect to the external endpoint. My YAML file is here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec: 
  containers:
    - name: dockertest20190205080020
      image: dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io/dockertest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 443
metadata: 
  name: my-test
  labels: 
    app: app-label
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-label
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
```

I can now see an external IP when I issue the command:

```
kubectl get service test-service --watch
```

However, if I try to connect to that IP I get a timeout exception.  I've tried running the dashboard, and it says everything is running fine. What I can do next to diagnose this issue?

Comment: does it work internally? can you access the service if you do: `kubectl port-forward svc/test-service 443` and then localhost:443? also, this wont work on https, it will work on http only

Comment: That command results in a timeout (if I give it a service name that doesn't exist then it tells me immediately that it doesn't exist).  When you say it won't work over https, do you mean the port forwarding, or are you saying assigning 443 generally won't work?

Comment: assigning port 443 should work, https wont. i'm actually not sure, can you try some other port. port-forwarding should work either way. you can try port-forward to the pod directly, but your service should work, so you need to port-forward to that

Comment: I tried changing the service config to have port: 80, targetPort: 443.  When I then run the port-forward command it tells me that it's handling connection for 80.  If I then try to connect to http://127.0.0.1:80/ I get a connection refused error

Comment: change all ports to 80 and try again. if that doesnt work try to port-forward to your pod

Comment: did it work for you mate?

Comment: No.  Although I'm happy to admit I might have it set up wrong.  I tried changing all the ports to 80 - same result.  I then changed all the ports to use a brand new port, including the container, re-created the cluster and did: kubectl port-forward pods/my-test 6666:6666. When I try to connect to http://127.0.0.1:6666/ I get connection refused

Comment: code inside the container listens on a specific port usually, you need to use that port

Comment: In the dockerfile, I have: EXPOSE 6666 - is that what you mean?

Comment: well, it doesnt matter what you have in dockerfile, only thing that matters is what port your application is using, can you reach your application from inside the pod with `curl localhost:6666`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inside the pod" - how would I do this?

Comment: do `kubectl exec -it podname bash` and do `curl localhost:6666` from inside the pod

Comment: Gives me connection refused: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 6666: Connection refused

Comment: well, something tells me your app doesnt really work

Comment: curl localhost:80 seems to work - so it looks like there's a misconfigured port somewhere

Comment: It's literally a Hello World app - just the bare bones of a .Net Core app

Comment: well, it doesnt work locally? you got any better explanation?

Comment: It does appear to on port 80 (see above).  I'm going to try tearing the whole thing down and re-building.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up getting it working by setting the container port to 80 and the external port to 6666.  Not sure why, but the container wouldn't work with any other port than 80 (or at least it wouldn't work with 6666)

Comment: @SmileyDev My answer pointed out your problem from the beginning, you need to look carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, the problem was solved by exposing container on port 80 and routing from external port 6666 to it.